# if_else with sequence of conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, tidyverse

I have the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df <- tibble(date = as_date(c("2019-11-20", "2019-11-27", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-15", "2020-09-23", "2020-11-25", "2021-03-03")))

# A tibble: 7 x 1
  date      
  <date>    
1 2019-11-20
2 2019-11-27
3 2020-04-01
4 2020-04-15
5 2020-09-23
6 2020-11-25
7 2021-03-03
```

I also have an ordered comparison vector of dates:

```
comparison <- seq(as_date("2019-12-01"), today(), by = "months") - 1
```

I now want to compare my dates in `df` to those comparison dates and so something like:

- if date in df is < comparison[1], then assign a 1
- if date in df is < comparison[2], then assign a 2
- and so on.

I know I could do it with a `case_when`, e.g.

```
df %>%
  mutate(new_var = case_when(date < comparison[1] ~ 1,
                             date < comparison[2] ~ 2))
```

(of course filling this up with all comparisons).

However, this would require to manually write out all sequential conditions and I'm wondering if I couldn't just automate it. I though about creating a match lookup first (i.e. take the comparison vector, then add the respective new_var number (i.e. 1, 2, and so on)) and then match it against my data, but I only know how to do that for exact matches and don't know how I can add the "smaller than" condition.

Expected result:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  date       new_var
  <date>       <dbl>
1 2019-11-20       1
2 2019-11-27       1
3 2020-04-01       6
4 2020-04-15       6
5 2020-09-23      11
6 2020-11-25      13
7 2021-03-03      17
```

Comment: Give `findInterval` a try.

Comment: Related: [Categorize numeric variable into group/ bins/ breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979456/categorize-numeric-variable-into-group-bins-breaks); [Categorical date variable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451344/categorical-date-variable-in-r)

Comment: `findInterval(df$date,comparison) + 1` gives you the expected result.

Comment: Wow, didn't think that it could be so easy. Thanks for your help. I'm happy to upvote and accept as an answer if you'd like to reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findInterval` as follows:

```
df %>% mutate(new_var = df$date %>%  findInterval(comparison) + 1)
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  date       new_var
  <date>       <dbl>
1 2019-11-20       1
2 2019-11-27       1
3 2020-04-01       6
4 2020-04-15       6
5 2020-09-23      11
6 2020-11-25      13
7 2021-03-03      17
```

Comment: Although this solution is correct (thanks for it!), it is exactly what was suggested in the comments, so I'd like to wait a bit until one of the commenters replied, since I would find it more fair to accept their answers.